# passing an object to a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object

This might seem like a noob question but I'm not sure what to do. I have function with 2 variables.

```
function someInfo(myVar1,myVar2)
{
    this.lmyVar1=myVar1;
    this.myVar2=myVar2;
}

myInstance=new someInfo("string1","string2");

function drawVariables(){
    document.write(myInstance.myVar1);
    document.write(myInstance.myVar2);
}
```

I want to use the same drawVariable() for multiple instances. I just can't figure out how the exact syntax for that. How can I make drawVariable() use a different instance of someInfo without repeating anything? Is there a simple example or tutorial I can follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it make sense for you to do it this way?

```
function someInfo(myVar1, myVar2)
{
    this.lmyVar1 = myVar1;
    this.myVar2 = myVar2;
    this.drawVariables = function ()
    {
        document.write(this.lmyVar1);
        document.write(this.myVar2);
    }
}


function Test()
{
    var obj1 = new someInfo("aaa", "bbb");
    var obj2 = new someInfo("xxx", "zzz");

    obj1.drawVariables();
    obj2.drawVariables();
}
```

Comment: I was looking for something a little more generic, but this is great. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Add an argument to the definition of function `drawVariables`. In the code below, this argument is called `info`. Now you can use `info` as your object inside the `drawVariables` function, and while calling `drawVariables` function, you can pass whatever instance you want to pass it. `drawVariables` function would now work with whatever instance you pass it while calling.

```
function someInfo(myVar1,myVar2)
{
    this.myVar1=myVar1;
    this.myVar2=myVar2;
}

// Create two separate instances
myInstance=new someInfo("string1", "string1");
myInstance2 = new someInfo("string2", "string2");

// info is the argument that represents the instance passed to this function
function drawVariables(info){
    alert(info.myVar1 + ", " + info.myVar2);
}

// Call the function twice with different instances
drawVariables(myInstance);
drawVariables(myInstance2);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/WLHuL/ for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

```
function drawVariables(instance){
    document.write(instance.myVar1);
    document.write(instance.myVar2);
}
```